# Git force push restoring old version to repo instead of new

Tags: git, github

I have a repo called WebScraper with a single branch called main. I am the sole contributor to the repo but do so from multiple machines. There is NO gitignore file. The program scrapes web data and updates a fairly small csv (<2k lines). It runs daily on machine1.

Currently on machine1 CSV was edited this morning (1/25) and I can verify there's new data as the last lines are dated 1/25. Currently on web repo CSV was updated on 1/23 and I can verify this as the last lines are dated 1/23.

Inside the WebScraper dir I use git push and get a 'Everything up-to-date' message. A. Why does it fail to recognize that CSV has been recently updated?

```
git push
```

Next I try deleting CSV from the web repo and retrying 'git push' on machine1. Machine1 commits some changes but the old 1/23 CSV appears on the web repo (verified via data inside).

B. Where is it getting the old CSV files from? How does it conjure a file into existence and then decide not to use the more recently modified version?

Next I try 'git push --force' from machine1. It goes through the enumerating, counting, delta compression, writing steps, says 100% done, gives comit numbers andsays --> main (forced update) BUT the CSV is still outdated.

```
git push --force
```

Comment: May you share the git commands you are using? As well as a simple git commit graph? (`git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --all --oneline --topo-order`)

Comment: "repo is already up to date" -- are you committing? "It says it pushed some files" -- this is not how git works.

Comment: Git does not push "changes" or "files". The coin of the realm is _commits_. Only a commit is a "thing" in Git.

Comment: A good idea is: before you push, say `git fetch`. That brings your _local_ remote tracking branches into sync with the actual remote.

Comment: I never used a 'git commit' command before and just 'git push' could that be an issue? I don't want 'git fetch' because I don't to overwrite the new data in local CSV from old data on remote

Comment: If you've never done a `git commit', then your repo will be empty and not contain anything.  So if your repo has the old file, you must have at some point done a commit with that old file.  Git push will push the last committed version to the upstream repo -- what is in the working tree or index is irrelevant (and not pushed).

Comment: @Garglesoap it sounds like you haven't been committing any code changes. Please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4), I think it will help you massively.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was I had not commited the changes prior to attempting to push them. Confusion arouse because I had been used to using GUI git interfaces (gitkraken) where they have a 'Stage' button that essentially is the same as commit. So Switching from GUI to CLI I wasn't aware of the need to commit prior to pushing. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Even in gitkraken staging is not the same as committing. Staging is using “git add”.